# Distribute coins fairly

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

$10$ coins weigh $10$ grams each, and another $10$ coins weigh $11$ grams each. So the average weight is:

$$\frac{10 \cdot 10 + 10 \cdot 11}{20} = 10.5\text{ grams}.$$

Now I need to distribute coins to $3$ persons: $5$ coins to A, $5$ to B and $10$ to C. How to distribute them fairly so the average weight of coins for each person is as close as $10.5$ grams?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- C can have an average of $10.5$g while A and B cannot: they can only achieve $10.4$g or $10.6$g.
- You might find it easier to see this by multiplying these by the numbers of coins: C could get a total of $105$g from ten coins while A and B can only get $52$g or $53$g from five coins each.

Comment: Thanks Henry, that's just an example, suppose there are many coins on different levels of weights, and many people, how to solve this issue algorithmically? It doesn't need to be exactly the same as 10.5, but need to be as close as possible.

Comment: In general I suspect there may not be a simple algorithm but instead you end up with a [discrete optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_optimization) problem.  It may depend on how you define "as close as possible". See [xkcd](http://www.xkcd.com/287/)